# Div background image change on hover of non-parent/non-sibling div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

This is a little bit of a complicated procedure, but I'll explain it as best I can. I'm creating a portfolio in wordpress and trying to include as much dynamism as I can.

I have a large banner image at the top of the page and individual thumbnails of my work below. What I'm looking to do is be able to hover over the thumbnails and have them fade the header image to larger version of the thumbnail, by using the same image source as the thumbnail.

To make matters more complex, the page thumbnails are generated by cycling through "portfolio" posts with featured images. This means that I don't have a hard copy of each link and need to instead generate it with similar PHP code that I'm using to create the thumbs.

I thought I might be able to do this with CSS only, but my research led me to find that it isn't doable if the elements aren't related to each other, either as parent or sibling.

Is this kind of thing even possible? I assume I'd have to use javascript, but my knowledge of the language is far inferior to my knowledge of CSS/HTML.

The website in question is [here](http://scottfischer.co/blog/).

EDIT:

This is the code I'm using to spawn thumbnails.

```
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 6, 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'));
        while($query->have_posts()) : 
            $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="portfolioThumbnail"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div><?php
            endwhile;
?>
```

In a nutshell, the site is comprised like so:

```
<div id="backgroundThatNeedsToChangeOnHover"></div>

<navigation></nav>

<div id="content">

    <div class="portfolioThumbnail">
        <a href="spawnedByPHP"><img src="spawnedByPHP" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="portfolioThumbnail">
        <a href="spawnedByPHP"><img src="spawnedByPHP" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="portfolioThumbnail">
        <a href="spawnedByPHP"><img src="spawnedByPHP" /></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please include relevant code in your post so that we can help you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified example using jquery: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/S2Ayp/)

```
$(function(){
  $('.thumb').click(function(){
    $('.header').css("backgroundImage", "url(" + $(this).attr("src") + ")");
  });
});
```

**Update with hover and fade in/out:** [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/S2Ayp/3/)

```
var url;
$(function(){
  $('.header').css("backgroundImage", "url( http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/9 )");
  $('.thumb').hover(function(){
    url = "url(" + $(this).attr("src") + ")";
    $('.header').animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function(){
      $(this).css("backgroundImage", url).delay(100).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This looks like it'd work nicely! Is there a way to add animation? Would changing it to work on hover be as simple as replacing "click" with "onmouseover"?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a small problem with the header being unable to return to the original image (which is the need for this code.) I came up with this. Does this work from an efficient code standpoint? I'd add animation to both events.

```
$(function(){
    var headImg = $('.header').css("backgroundImage");

  $('.thumb').mouseover(function(){
    $('.header').css("backgroundImage", "url(" + $(this).attr("src") + ")");
  });

  $('.thumb').mouseleave(function(){
      $('.header').css("backgroundImage", headImg);
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2Ayp/4/)

**Updated JSFiddle with fade in/out and stop animation** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QmP7p/2/)

```
$(function(){
    var headImg = $('.header').css("backgroundImage");
    var url;

  $('.thumb').mouseover(function(){
      url = "url(" + $(this).attr("src") + ")";
      $('.header').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 250, function(){
      $(this).css("backgroundImage", url).animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
      });
  });

  $('.thumb').mouseleave(function(){
      $('.header').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 250, function(){
          $(this).css("backgroundImage", headImg).animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
      });
  });
});
```

UPDATE: Wordpress does not understand delay(). Removed it from the code.